# Load multiple views using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ngroute

I have a scenario like this:

```
<a href="#">Link1</a>
<a href="#">Link2</a>

<div id="child1"></div>
<div id="child2"></div>
```

- When I click on link1 I expect to load **View A** in div child 1 and **View B** in div child2.
- When I click on link2 I expect to load **View C** in div child 1 and **View D** in div child2

I'm using ngRoute (standard AngularJS router) in my app.

---

*i.e:* I expect a different set of views for different links. How can this be accomplished using AngularJS. I understand that Angular does provide routing, but whatever examples I see online is only for a single view.

I have kept this scenario very simple. In reality it is a lot more complicated so I will not be able to combine 2 views into 1 for each link.

Comment: Is this for angularjs 1.x or angular 2? Are you using the vanilla angular router or ui-router?

Comment: I am using angular 1.6.4. I am so far using the standard angular router not the ui-router

Comment: Thanks @Mistalis. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another suggestion, you can use `ui-router` and [multiple named views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) it's easy to use and really powerful.

You can create your different view container using `ui-view` like this

```
<a href="#" >Link1</a>

<a href="#" >Link2</a>

<div ui-view="child1"></div>
<div ui-view="child2"></div>
```

And in you `app.config`, you can set for every states which template you want to load for the different views :

```
.state('report', {      
    views: {        
      'child1': { ... templates and/or controllers ... },       
      'child2': {}      
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have another question. We we switch back and forth between views using ui-router (by changing routes/states) can we retain the data of the previous view. We have cases where users could be on View 1. Enter some data. Then decides to switch to View 2. Then again decides to come back to View 1. In that case would he have access to all the data he previously entered on View 1

Comment: @RiteshMehta You can store your data in [providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) or in [cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) which are both not refreshed on a state/view change

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion:

#### 1) Make 4 templates (one per view):

- viewA.html
- viewB.html
- viewC.html
- viewD.html

#### 2) Set 2 routes on your app (one per link):

```
$routeProvider.when('/page1', {
    templateUrl: 'page1.html',
    controller: 'Page1Ctrl'
}).when('/page2', {
    templateUrl: 'page2.html',
    controller: 'Page2Ctrl'
});
```

#### 3) Include the views in page link1.html and link2.html

```
<!-- page1.html -->
<div id="child1" ng-include="'viewA.html'"></div>
<div id="child2" ng-include="'viewB.html'"></div>
```

```
<!-- page2.html -->
<div id="child1" ng-include="'viewC.html'"></div>
<div id="child2" ng-include="'viewD.html'"></div>
```

#### 3) Set your `<a>` tags

```
<a href="#/page1">Link1</a>
<a href="#/page2">Link2</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I said initially it will be extremely difficult to combine sets of views (as you recommended) due to complexities that I do not want to get into.

Comment: @Ritesh You can set as much as you wish views with `ng-include`, use a variable for `templateUrl`... From what you provide, it is *-imo-* the cleanest solution. Maybe could you explain how and why your real scenario is more complex?